# Equality in R - Precision?

Tags: r

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but how is

```
sqrt(144) == 12^2
```

False

```
> sqrt(144)
[1] 12
> 12^2
[1] 144
```

My gut is that it has something to do with precision, but curious as to understand why this takes shape.

Comment: it would be simialr to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems like  you're asking why `12 == 144` is `False`?

Comment: Yeah `sqrt(144) == 12`, not `sqrt(144) == 12^2`

Comment: This should probably have been "closed as typo", not "closed as dupe" (`sqrt(144)==12` is `TRUE`)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's precision...

```
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=22)
sqrt(144) * 10000000000000
[1] 1199999999999999899362824

> 12 * 100000000000000000000000
[1] 1199999999999999899362824
```

On R 3.5.2 on Windows 10

Comment: on what system?  i get `sqrt(144)*10000000000000000000
[1] 120000000000000000000`

Comment: Windows 10, R 3.5.2. That's interesting...

Comment: Interestingly, I get your result when I run the same in R 3.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 inside Windows 10.

Comment: OK, chalk it up to "floating point is unreliable ..." - which we knew already